# Using returned ajax ID in other calls to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have an ajax call that successfully calls a php file that inserts data and returns the ID of that insert, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to hold it in my main templates.php file (where the ajax code is) and keep it there to be used in mysql inserts/updates in other calls that need the ID.

templates.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitForm").click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
var string = $('#pageForm').serialize();

// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addPage.php",
    data: string,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

      $('#my_modal').modal('hide');
      $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    }
});

});

});
</script>
```

addPage.php

```
$addpage = "
INSERT INTO pages (title, page_type_id, display_id, duration)
VALUES ('$title','$page_type','$display_id','$duration');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addpage) === TRUE) {
$last_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
$data['last_insert_id'] = $last_id;
echo json_encode($data);
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $addpage . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

So when I do this, My console log prints: `"{\"last_insert_id\":67}"`

How can I save this ID to use in other calls in the page? For instance, I have this other ajax call:

```
var string = $('#form-data').serialize();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "addPanel.php",
          data: string,
          cache: false,
          success: function(response){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

          }
      });
```

and it calls:

addPanel.php

```
$panelID = $_POST['panel_type'];
$addPanel = "
INSERT panels(panel_type_id,  cont_id)
VALUES ('$panelID',  '$cont_id');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addPanel) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $addPanel . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

but I want to change the insert statement to use the previously returned "last_insert_id" as $page_id like so:

```
INSERT panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
  VALUES ('$panelID','$page_id', '$cont_id');
```

Comment: You can either use session variables with a specific key to identify last inserted ID. Or you can call Ajax call in Ajax call. Thereby passing `success` inside another.

Comment: You could store it in a global variable, and then use that variable in later calls.

Comment: Why cant you do everything in one Ajax call?

Comment: I would be fine either way, but the only reason I have them separated right now is to test individual functionality. In this case, the user creates a page title, thereby creating a page record and then they can create panels of content on the page, but each needs to reference that page. They use different buttons to save each @AkintundeOlawale

Comment: @Barmar I know how to do that with php, but I'm new to using Ajax. How would I store that as global to be used in other ajax calls?

Comment: In the success function you do `globalVariable = response;`

Comment: @Barmar oh so I could create the variable within the page Submission success function? But then how would I call that in the mysql update or insert script?

Comment: FYI you don't need `cache: false`. POST is never cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a hidden input in the form that you send to the next AJAX call:

```
<input type="hidden" id="page_id" name="page_id">
```

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submitForm").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var string = $('#pageForm').serialize();

    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "addPage.php",
      data: string,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $("#page_id").val(response.last_insert_id);

        $('#my_modal').modal('hide');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
      }
    });
  });
```

In `addPanel.php` you get it from `$_POST['page_id']`.

Note that anything that comes from the client is suspect. If you don't want the user to be able to change this, it would be better to save it in a session variable in PHP, rather than rely on the client to send it back. But if the client can actually add a panel to any page, and this is just for convenience so they don't have to enter the page ID, this method should be fine.

Comment: I've made these changes and now my console log says: ```Undefined index: page_id in C:\\addPanel.php on line 25\nError: \r\n\tINSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)\r\n\tVALUES ('2', '', '70');\r\n<br>Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'page_id' at row 1```
It looks like it's not getting the integer of the page ID when it's returned originally

Comment: I've changed my answer to just show how to do it with a hidden input. This is simpler and less error prone.

Comment: I'm using console.log since I have other forms on the page with POST method, but console shows ```"{\"last_insert_id\":67}"``` on the initial ajax call

Comment: I asked that because I wanted to see what is being received by the second AJAX call.

Comment: I think the problem, even after trying your new edit, is that when I do my first call that inserts on addpage.php, it returns the correct ID of the insert but it isn't recognizing it as an integer for the insert. I get the same error with your newest edit that it is incorrect integer value for column page_id

Comment: I can't see any reason for that. What does `var_dump($_POST)` show in `addPanel.php`?

Comment: BTW, you really should learn how to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into SQL. Your code is wide open to SQL-injection.

Comment: it shows the array with the other 2 values correct but empty for page_id ```[\"panel_type\"]=>\n  string(1) \"3\"\n  [\"page_id\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"halfRightText\"]=>\n  string(89)```

Comment: And I definitely do intend to prepare everything, just testing the main functions right now

Comment: It's sending an empty `page_id`. Are you sure the second AJAX call is happening after the first one has completed?

Comment: What triggers the second AJAX call?

Comment: So, a modal on page load triggers the first ajax call that creates a page and page_id. Then within the page there is another modal instance with a textarea and a submit button that triggers the 2nd ajax call

Comment: Here's the other thing, response.last_insert_id prints 'undefined' in console log. if I just log 'response' it shows the full string of {last_insert_id: 67}

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` to the AJAX call.

Comment: I assumed you were already parsing it as JSON, since you use `JSON.stringify()` when you log it.

Comment: OH, I see. Add that to the first ajax call?

Comment: Add it to all AJAX calls that are supposed to receive a JSON response. And when PHP is reporting an error, it should encode that as JSON as well.

Comment: E.g. `echo json_encode(array('error' => $mysqlConn->error));`

Comment: I added it to the first call, with no improvement. I then added it to the 2nd call that would need it to insert on addpanel.php and it broke the submission to the database. I'll just have to keep messing with it I guess

Comment: Does it have anything to do with passint in the intial data as a string, but then expecting JSON as the datatype in the response